# Import and transform data from the web

Tags: r

this is kind of a re-port, but basically a new post, since I made a lot of progress since my original post.  Here's my objective: get xml data into a data frame.  I'm running this script.

```
# install and load the necessary package
install.packages("XML")
library(XML)
# Save the URL of the xml file in a variable

xml.url <- "http://www.usda.gov/oce/commodity/wasde/report_format/latest-July-2015-New-Format.xml"
# Use the xmlTreePares-function to parse xml file directly from the web

xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse(xml.url)
# the xml file is now saved as an object you can easily work with in R:
class(xmlfile)



# Use the xmlRoot-function to access the top node
xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile)
# have a look at the XML-code of the first subnodes:
print(xmltop)[1:3]
```

Everything seems fine up to that point.  The next line seems to NOT parse the data as I thought it would.

```
# To extract the XML-values from the document, use xmlSApply:
datacat <- xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
```

I did some research on this, and it seemed to work in other examples of xml data.  I guess this data set is different...or I just don't understand this well enough to know what's really going on...

Basically, I want to get this:

```
xmltop
```

Into a data table.  How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I know that the rows and columns are NOT the same.  I read online that I need to 'melt' the dataset.  Does that sound right?